# CORS não sendo aplicados - Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cors

Tenho uma classe de configuração do Spring Boot para lidar com CORS. Essa classe, teoricamente, permite todas as origens, de todos os métodos e com todos os headers.

```
@Configuration
public class CorsConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("*").allowedOrigins("*").allowedHeaders("*");
    }
}
```

Todavia, no front end, recebo:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at ‘http://172.17.178.81:3000/api/v1/token’
>   from origin ‘http://172.17.0.75:8002’ has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Response to preflight request doesn’t pass access control check: No
>   ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ header is present on the requested
>   resource.

Quando eu anoto meu endpoint com @CrossOrigin, funciona normalmente.

Gostaria de saber o que pode ser feito. Não acredito que anotar todo endpoint com @CrossOrigin seja o certo a ser feito.

Comment: Anotei com:

@ Configuration (já estava)
@ EnableWebMvc
@ ComponentScan
E aparentemente funcionou. Todavia, é certo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anotei a classe com @EnableWebMvc e tudo pareceu funcionar tranquilamente.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class CorsConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("*").allowedOrigins("*").allowedHeaders("*");
    }
}
```